# Jmeter jenkins doesnt store past builds result

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing

I setup my jmeter to run on jenkins daily. Everything works fine except the past jenkins build automatically flip to fail status the next day when a new schedule run kicks in and it also removed the past build results. I attached a screenshot of the build history. For sep 12, they were all green.

Anyone experience this issue or know which area I can look into?

My goal is to try to compare with past build result and send an email if the performance didn't pass criteria.

I am happy to share more details.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your jenkins configuration ? which plugins you used and show their version. Thanks

Comment: HI, yup, I am using Performance plugin 3.17 from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/performance/ . I appreciate your help.  Thanks let me know what else I can provide

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we're not telepathic enough to guess the reason by looking at a single screenshot.

1. Double check your job configuration, especially location of the JMeter's [jtl result files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) as it might be the case you're storing them in current job folder instead of workspace
2. Double check your [Performance Plugin configuration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin/), especially "thresholds" section
3. Inspect [`Console Output`](https://plugins.jenkins.io/display-console-output) for the previous/latest builds
4. Check [*jenkins.log* file](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging) for any suspicious entries